# What is the difference between a RoutedCommand and a RoutedUICommand?

Tags: .net, wpf, routed-commands

I have tried to do some reading about it, but I failed to find documentation that explains the difference between RoutedCommand and RoutedUICommand satisfactorily.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

RoutedUICommand derives from RoutedCommand and adds a text field used to provide a description of the command. This is useful when the command is bound to be accessed from the UI.

I got this from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routeduicommand?view=netframework-4.8).

> The difference between a RoutedUICommand and RoutedCommand is that RoutedUICommand includes a Text property.

Comment: As if now (November, 2020) the exact link for the above code is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routeduicommand?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)